# Error: While Creating new iOS App on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I'm not able to create new app in itunes connect.When I try to create a new app it shows me the message "You have no eligible Bundle IDs for iOS apps."
Although I created app id in apple developer portal and followed every possible solution but unable to create a new app in iTunes connect
[Error While Creating New iOS App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeyCb.png)
My developer entity type is "Company/Organization"

Comment: Did you try to add New App Bundle option in itunesconnect.com?

Comment: Yes, i already did that and it shows me the following results as you can see in image (https://cloudup.com/ccZj5dKBRr7)

Comment: once i had a strange problem with the itunes..and wrote a mail to apple describing the problems...later on they opened ticket and resolved that...

Comment: @anishparajuli this is actually driving me nuts, when i try to contact apple support they redirect me to https://cloudup.com/cZg1eWMQ8JK

Comment: make sure you have agreed to the latest contract ?

Comment: @anishparajuli sorry i am a newbie to iOS programming.Can you please guide me where would I find that contract?